# Communicating via separate network cards

Tags: linux, networking, internet, nic

Assume you have a web server with two network cards (and their associated ports), let's call them A and B. The idea is to connect one port (A) to the internet and the other (B) to some isolated network of servers for various computations. This seems to be relatively common, one network exposed to the internet for the actual sending and receiving of information and a private network for secure data storage, administrative control, etc.

How would traffic be directed through one or the other? The only side I've seen to this is the code side, and in all languages I'm familiar with, you initiate communication (TCP, say) by providing a destination address, not an origin  address. If you want to talk to a specific machine connected (via switch) to one port or the other, how would you specify which? Moreover, what if you had machines connected via both A and B but some traffic (maybe financial information) would need to be sent through B while other traffic (REST data, for example) would be a better fit for A?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably do this with routing - have one subnet on port A and another subnet on port B. Then the OS will route the packets through the correct interface according to the service it needs to reach.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: If a machine is reachable through both interfaces, you can use source routing to control outgoing traffic. In linux that means creating additional ip routing tables and creating ip rules which, based on conditions, specify which routing table shoud be used.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what and why do you need to do.

If you have 2 network cards, your machine will have 2 network connections and 2 IP addresses. When you communicate with some other machine via IP address of that machine, your server will choose outgoing interface based on the local routing policy, e.g. metric.

**Example 1:** you are connected to 2 networks:

- 10.0.0.0, where you have IP address 10.10.10.2
- 192.168.1.0, where you have IP address 192.168.1.2

Now, if you want to connect to 192.168.1.5, your web server will most likely choose 2nd network (192.168.1.0), since the destination is directly reachable there.

**Example 2:**, connected to 1 network only:

- 192.168.1.0, where you have IP address 192.168.1.2 and gateway 192.168.1.1

Now, if you want to  connect to 10.10.10.2, your web server will just send the packets to the default gateway (router), since 10.10.10.2 is not in your network (192.168.1.0). Your server has no clue, what happens with your packets on the gateway and how the gateway (router) will deliver it to the final destination. This is the headache of the gateway (router) only.

For the second example, the local routing table on your server will look quite easy:

- 192.168.1.* directly connected
- 0.0.0.0 (everything else) is connected through 192.168.1.1 (your gateway)

**Conclusion:**

From the code side, you cannot choose the outgoing interface, if you are not writing a routing software. This is reasonable, since you application has no idea about routing protocols, information and rules. The operating system makes the choice for you, depending on the routing table. And the routing table is created and updated by operating system depending on status of your network connections, policies, rules, routing protocols (if you server acts as a router) and so on.

If you DO NEED to communicate with the same destination through 2 different outgoing interfaces, depending on the destination PORT, then you should configure your routing on the server. Example for Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port

Comment: The question is two-fold. First, how do I explicitly choose where the traffic I send out goes (the only reasonable answer is routing tables?). Second, how do I react differently based on data received from the different interfaces. Let's say a given request asking for information received on B would be perfectly valid, whereas that same request received on A would imply some attacker is trying to access back-end data. Different ports? What if the ports to be used are standard, and used directly by some service, and therefore can't be changed? Sorry, I'm a lot more familiar with software.

Comment: First, yes, you need to configure routing (not directly the routing table, but routing rules and policies, depending on your OS) on the server, your application should not control it. Second - you need to configure the firewall, or have your application listening only on 1 interface.

Comment: For the second, imagine, that your server is reachable to a valid client through both interfaces. Then something in the network fails, then the network cannot reach you over B, and forwards the packets from valid client so, that they reach you through A. Then what, your client will become an attacker? Of course, not.

Comment: I'm not separating networks for fun, the idea is to separate potentially dangerous data coming in from some user somewhere on the internet from trusted data that could only possibly come from other machines in the same room working on the same problems. This separation is basically a security check. While ideally every packet would be checked and double checked to make sure it's not malicious, some data (log data for instance) is being sent in such quantities that it's not practical. If log data is used somewhere down the line to, say, restore passwords, injecting logs could be a valid attack.

Comment: To simplify (and not need to create and attach a diagram) I said there was only one web server. In actuality, this web server is one of many, each connected via a switch (and router, firewall, etc.) to the internet on A, and to servers handling data, complex computation, etc. (again via switch) on B. Because the web servers share a switch on either interface, they could communicate with each other through either, which could be helpful if, for example, one was overloaded with requests and needed to pass off some to another web server. This would be best done using A, rather than B.

Comment: First of all, you need to figure out, what do you need. It could be a very bad idea to decide if the request is valid based on the incoming interface. Rather, you should decide based on the source IP or something else. E.g., from example 1, you allow only clients from 192.168.1.0 network to send request for back-end data (using firewall rules). And, based on your network configuration (ask your system administrator), only valid clients could have IP address from that network.

Comment: Forget about interfaces then. You have 2 networks connected: A (Internet, demilitarised zone) and B (local, trusted network). Based on the configuration of your network, NOT your single server, only trusted clients could get into network B. Then, only allow access (using firewall) to clients from B (based on their source IP address). If you have external client that need to get into B over Internet - use VPN. Now the topic becomes too long to discuss it further in comments, and you need more understanding about networking or an advice from security professional knowing about your setup.

Comment: Would you mind providing a few search terms I could look into for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21096/discussion-between-andrey-sapegin-and-theenvironmentalist).

Answer (score 2):

This is why you normally assign different host names, or maybe different subdomains, to your different interfaces.

Assume your hostnames are host001 and host002, and your network looks like this:

```
<-----internet --------+------------------------------+-------whatever else--->
                       |                              |
          157.38.5.6   |                  157.38.5.7  |
       +---------------+--+             +-------------+--+
       |  host001         |             |  host002       |
       +---------------+--+             +-------------+--+
          192.168.1.1  |                  192.168.1.2 |
                       +------------------------------+-------admin lan--->
```

157.38.5/24 is the address range assigned to you by your provider. Both hosts are reachable from the internet, and you'd put

```
host001.mycompany.com. IN A 157.38.5.6
host002.mycompany.com. IN A 157.38.5.7
```

into your official DNS records.

(Please note that there should be a big *firewall* box in your internet connection, and you probably shouldn't use publicly routable addresses anywhere but on your firewall. But i wanted the distinction between inside/outside for clarity).

Into your company-internal DNS server, whose records aren't published on the internet, you'd put

```
host001.dmz.company.com IN A 157.38.5.6
host002.dmz.company.com IN A 157.38.5.7
host001.mgm-net.company.com IN A 192.168.1.1
host002.mgm-net.company.com IN A 192.168.1.2
```

Now, whenever you want to open a connection over the internal network, you'd use one of the host names within the `mgm-net` domain. This will select the `192.168.1` addresses, and, since each of the hosts has one of those on its own, it will use this network interface. If you want to use the public network, use the `dmz` domain addresses.

**How does the local host select the outgoing interface**?

This is what the routing table is for. Your routing table will look similar to this :

```
destination     netmask             gateway      metric  interface
    0.0.0.0     0.0.0.0             157.38.5.1        1       eth0
 157.38.5.0     255.255.255.0                         0       eth0
 192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0                         0       eth1
```

The exact format of the table depends on your OS, OS version, and command used to display it. Also, the absolute values of the metric may be different.
The key in this is that from all routing table entries, the kernel will eliminate those that don't fit the destination address. If you connect to 192.168.1.1, this will remove the second entry (157...) from the list. The default route (0.0.0.0) is still elegible at this point.

Then, from all remaining possibilities, the one with the best metric is chosen. Classically, metric was a synonym for the number of hops to the destination, so the lowest metric was best. Windows uses the other way, highest metric is best. Anyway, it's the combination of possible routes, and metrics, in your local routing table, that decides which local interface is used.

This is especially important if you're trying to connect from a place "further down the network" within your company, where there are one or more routers between your PC and the target networks.

**Possibilities to improve this further**

- You might want to give diffent host names, instead of different network domains, to your hosts. So you might have a host001-ext.mycompany.com and a host001-adm.mycompany.com host entry, so you don't have to "spell out" the domain every time you connect to a specific host. However, by messing with the domain search order on different PCs, you can do some tricks where PC A prefers dmz.company.com, PC B prefers mgm-net.company.com, and the "autoselect" the correct network if the just see "host001" in a configuration file.
- You will get less confusion if you synchronize the last IP bytes; 157.38.5.6 on the outside should match 192.178.1.6 on the inside, not 192.168.1.1. Having consistent last bytes allows you to create a script that auto-generates internal addresses from external ones.
- "Dangerous" services, like Port 22/ssh (on unix) or 3389/remote desktop can/should be bound on the 192.168.1.X addresses only. That way, you can still ssh into your machine if you're on the internal network, but you've removed an attack vector from the outside.

**Configuration / Programming**

One of the function of OS APIs is to hide the gory details of all that, so you don't see any differences in "which interface does the data come from" unless you specifically ask for it.

From a C socket API, you could use the `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` functions to find out about the local/remote addresses of a socket. And when you use `bind()` to set up a listening socket, one of the parameters is the `sockaddr` structure, in which you have to set the port, and in which you *may* set the ip address. Normally, you just set it to 0.0.0.0, which means the socket is bound to that port on any address.

In Java, you have `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()` and `Socket.getInetAddress` to do the same, and `ServerSocket()` has a 3-parameter version which lets you set the address to listen on.

Applications typically have configuration files to do the same. For example, the `sshd` configuration in `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` has a `ListenAddress` parameter. If you say `ListenAddress 192.168.1.1` here, then `sshd` will pass that `192.168.1.1` to `bind()` when creating the socket, and your OS won't accept ssh packets destinated to `157.38.5.6`.

Likewise the apache web server has a configuration parameter `Listen` that allows you to set the port, and optionally the address, to listen on.

Windows Programs have this in some configuration clickies, normally. In IIS, you bind services to servers using a port and IP address (where the address can be '*' for all addresses) which effectively does the same.

Comment: This was very helpful. A few questions, though. First, security of course takes precedence, how to you 'bind' dangerous services to specific addresses? Second, what about input? I'm used to listening on various ports, but how does the NIC used map to the port. In other words, if I was receiving data on one interface on port 80, and on the other interface on port 80, would the two sets of incoming data look identical from within the code?

Comment: See edits. The OS shields you from these details unless you explicitly ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

From your text I'm not sure if you're really talking about two really separate networks, i.e.:

1. One different switch for each subnet (or a single managed switch, with more than one VLAN);
2. Each switch connects to one NIC (network card) on your server;
3. all the other computers connect only to a single switch;
4. Each subnet has it's own addressing, for example, one has addresses like 192.168.0.*, and the other 192.1.68.1.*

If that is indeed the case, then:

1. Linux on the server should route traffic **automatically** from one network to the other (if not, Google iptables, routing between two NICS, and tell us which Linux you're running)
2. The server is also a good place to configure **a firewall to restrict** the traffic you don't want to route across networks.
3. The distinction of which way the traffic goes is simply based on IP addresses (see 4 above).
4. Normally you wouldn't connect PC's on both subnets, you would rather work with the routing and firewall (on a single point, the server) to fine-tune what travels across subnets.